# Centering responisive text on top of a header image

Tags: html, css

My code is a mess. I just started a website and I am trying to vertically and horizontally center a piece of text on top of a header image, while making it mobile responsive.

```css
#index_header {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#index_header img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.background_title {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 64px;
  left: 50% top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>HOME</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fluid_index.css" />

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <body>

    <div class="page_container">
      <div id="index_header">
        <a href="#">
          <img alt="slider" id="index_headerimg" src="http://www.bakeryandsnacks.com/var/plain_site/storage/images/publications/food-beverage-nutrition/bakeryandsnacks.com/regulation-safety/coles-freshly-baked-claims-false-rules-federal-court-australia/9101085-1-eng-GB/Coles-freshly-baked-claims-false-rules-Federal-Court-Australia.jpg"
          />
          <p class="background_title">G.F. Bakery</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

If anyone could help me that would be amazing.

Comment: For starters, you never close your `<head>` tag...

Comment: sorry it was a copy and paste error

Answer (score 0):

It did work when I tried it, but you're missing a ; in your css.
Try this:

```
.background_title {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 64px;
  left: 50%; 
  top: 50%;
}
```

You didn't close the 'left'.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I feel quite silly for that, but if you notice still when I fix that, the css is only centering the first letter which makes it out of line slightly

Comment: How do you mean only the first letter? Made a Fiddle, this is what you wanted right? https://jsfiddle.net/c2bom0cc/1/ If not please let me know.

Comment: The text is not centered, as you can see it leans right compared to the actual center of the image